# Rappasoft sortable column is not allowing sorting

Tags: laravel, datatable

I'm building a job table using rappasoft/laravel-livewire-datatables and I now have all columns showing and all is looking good. I do however have a few issues remaining, The main one is that although the clients column is defined as sortable it does not change pointer and doesn't do anything if the header is clicked. Here is my Column def from the columns() function

```
            LinkColumn::make('Client')
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable()
                ->title(fn($row) => $row->client->title)
                ->location(fn($row) =>  '/client/' . $row->client->id . '/show'),
```

So as you can see I use the $jobs->client to get the data and it shows the Title in the table. How do I make it work?

Comment: I think you need user-defined sorting for that you can refer this https://rappasoft.com/docs/laravel-livewire-tables/v1/columns/using-the-built-in-sorting

Comment: Ah, I'm going to look over that part of the docs and see if can get this working!